# SysteVerilog, UVM uvm_reg_adapter. Is there way use uvm_sequences instead uvm_sequence_item

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have to create adapter for register Layer. I do have sequences to access bus which i like to reuse.
Currently adapter should return item and reg layer will do start_item.
Is there any way use sequences and reg layer will do just start.
Thanks,

Comment: I think `uvm_reg_adapter` class is to use sequence with `uvm_reg_item` and if you want to use your `uvm_sequence`, then you should be allowed to do that without any `uvm_reg_adapter`

Answer (score 2):

Look in the user guide for `frontdoor` sequence. There's a `uvm_reg_frontdoor` class that is a `uvm_sequence`. You can use this as an adapter between register accesses and your bus sequences.

Comment: Thanks, works. Only small inconvenience this method can be set for uvm_reg, and not to entire uvm_reg_block. So i have to probably set it for each register in side the block.

Comment: @AlbertWaissman You can loop over all registers inside a block and create a new frontdoor sequence for each.